# How can I see LESS line numbers in Firefox inspect element (Q) while using Less in the browser compilation mode

Tags: less

I am new LESS, want to know how can I see LESS line numbers in Firefox Inspect Element (Q). 
I am using Less in the Browser compilation mode.

Please see codes below...

**HTML**

```
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Document</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet/less" type="text/css" href="main.less" />
    <script>
    less = {
        env: 'development',
        async: false,
        fileAsync: false,
        poll: 1000,
        dumpLineNumbers: 'all',
        relativeUrls: false,
        rootpath: false,
        useFileCache: false
    };
    </script>
     <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/less.js/2.5.1/less.min.js"></script>
    <script>less.watch();</script> <!--  -->
</head>

<body>
    <div class="class1">
        <div class="class2">Sample Text</div>
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

**LESS**

```
 @color1: green;
 @color2: yellow;
 @border-radius:20px;
.class1 {
    background-color: @color1;
    border-radius:@border-radius;
    padding:  30px;
    width: 500px;
    .class2 {
        background-color: @color2;
        color: @color1;
        padding:  10px;
        border-radius:  @border-radius/20;
        font-size: 20px;
        text-align: center;
    }
}
```

**OUTPUT**

As you can see [here](http://s11.postimg.org/ubl7cs5nn/ss1.png) (Sorry, I don't have 10 reputation to directly attach image here), less file compiled successfully, but not showing line number in inspect element. Please let me know what is the configuration change required to see the exact less file name and line number here.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: It won't. Because `dumpLineNumbers` only emits those line numbers as comments in the compiled CSS (And style viewers in browsers don't show any comments). In general, you will need to switch from client-side compilation to server-side (where a server can be your own machine, with live-reloading available in most of common project build tool chains like `grunt`/`gulp`) and then use [sourcemaps](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools/Style_Editor#Source_map_support).

Comment: Thankss even-phases-max !

Comment: Siva, I am facing same problem. can you tell me how you have been resolve this issue?